# How to use modules in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module

I have a script that I want to call modules from.  I want the modules to reside in a modules folder.  So my main script has the following line

```
require "modules/01httpserver"
```

My 01httpserver modules is in a file named "01httpserver.rb" and it's in the modules folder.  The file contains the following code.

```
module 01httpserver
    def self.helloworld(name)
        puts "Hello, #{name}"
    end
end
```

So when I run the main script and it trieds to load the module file, I get the following error message: "`require': cannot load such file -- modules/01httpserver (LoadError)"

What could be causing this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure 'require' is searching your `$PATH` for the file. Your current directory is not, by default, located on your `$PATH` If you want to require a file relative to your directory, you might want to look into `require_relative` http://extensions.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Kernel.html

Comment: show your `main file`s die and `module` diretory tree in the post.

Comment: You cannot start name of the module with a digit - it has to be capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `require_relative`. Like:

```
require_relative "modules/01httpserver"
```

http://extensions.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Kernel.html

Comment: I ended up trying this and it worked. However when I use "01httpserver.helloworld("something")", it'll give me the following error: "syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end", then it says "01httpserver.helloworld("something")" and have a ^ pointing to the . between 01httpserver and helloworld.  Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: That's a different question, but basically constant names need to start with a capital letter, starting with a digit is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `require`, it iterates over the `$LOAD_PATH` variable and tries to find matching file in any of the paths. I found it extremely useful to add your project root to this variable. On top of your main file add:

```
$:.unshift File.dir_name(__FILE__)
```

And then you can use require with paths relative to the root.